# Aliasing function template with known type

Tags: c++, templates, alias

If I want to alias a template class for a known type in c++, I do something like this :

```
using MyVector = std::vector<MyClass>;
```

How do I ahieve the same for function templates?

```
template <typename T> void MyFunction(T MyValue);
```

I tried :

```
using MyIntFunction = MyFunction<int>;
```

But its not working.

Comment: I would use `auto&& MyIntFunction = [](int v){ MyFunction(v); }; ` ; In my opinion, a function in C++ is natively a singleton, not a type/class, and it is not possible for aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

Alias declarations are meant to introduce aliases for types.

Anyway, you can use a `constexpr` variable to do what (I suspect) you are trying to do:

```
constexpr auto MyIntFunction = &MyFunction<int>;
```

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
void MyFunction(T MyValue) {
    std::cout << MyValue << std::endl;
}

constexpr auto MyIntFunction = &MyFunction<int>;

int main() {
    MyIntFunction(42);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use template aliases for functions, there is no such syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that