# Conditional templated type aliases in scope of templated function

Tags: c++, templates, alias

Say I have `N` functions which have an indentical set of arguments.  I call a factory method with the arguments, and some value that allows me to choose between the `N` functions.

An untidy approach is to do an if statement like so:

```
if(choice == 1)
    foo_one<T>(args);
else if (choice == 2)
    foo_two<T>(args);
etc
```

This is fine, except in my case where the number of arguments is large.  Thus the factory method is very crowded.

Say I have a main function which calls the factory method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int choice = 1;
    float arg = 1.5;
    foo_choose(choice, arg);
    return 0;
}
```

I am thinking branching on the `choice` argument, and in that if statement setting an function alias.

That means that I would only need to pass my arguments once, regardless of how large `N` is.

It might look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo_one(T arg) { std::cout << "foo_one\n"; };

template <typename T>
void foo_two(T arg) { std::cout << "foo_one\n"; };

template <typename T>
void foo_choose(int choice, T arg)
{
    if(choice == 1)
        using foo = foo_one<T>;
    else
        using foo = foo_two<T>;        

    foo(arg);
};
```

However, I can't get this to work with the templates.  Is there something obvious I'm missing, or a search term I should be adding.

Since I might call `foo_choose` several times with different values for `choice`, I wouldn't want the alias `foo` to exist outside of the function scope.

[This question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284076/aliasing-function-template-with-known-type) maybe I'm on the wrong track, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To choose between things in a template at compile-time, you need `if constexpr`. But you can't check things like `choice` with that if as it's a run-time parameter.

Comment: So `using` is something that is applied at compile time rather than runtime?

Comment: Yes. `using` has multiple different uses but they are all compile-time things.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with

```
template <typename T>
void foo_choose(int choice, T arg)
{
    if(choice == 1)
        using foo = foo_one<T>;
    else
        using foo = foo_two<T>;        

    foo(arg);
};
```

Is that the using statements are scoped statements.  That means they only apply to he scope that are declared in so once you get to `foo(arg);`, `foo` is out of scope and you get an error.  Instead of getting an alias to the function, you can get a pointer to it, and then you call the pointer at the end.  That woudls look like

```
template <typename T>
void foo_choose(int choice, T arg)
{
    using f_ptr = void(*)(T);
    f_ptr foo;
    if(choice == 1)
        foo = foo_one<T>;
    else
        foo = foo_two<T>;        

    foo(arg);
};
```

This does come with the caveat that you have to specify all of the function template parameters.

Comment: Should probably mention that this requires 1. `foo_one` not being overloaded and 2. all template arguments of `foo_one` being spelt out (if any).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Added about the templates.  It works if it is overloaded though since the assignment acts as a static cast.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a79550b93139db50

Comment: This is a good solution to what I need, thanks.  @MaxLanghof, thankfully 2. does not apply to my use-case, but I can imagine that being an issue

Answer (score 1):

If all your candidates are functions of the same type, you could simply set up a local array of function pointers and choose from that:

```
template <typename T>
void foo_choose(int choice, T arg)
{
    constexpr void (*funcs[])(T) = { foo_one<T>, foo_two<T> };

    assert(choice > 0 && choice < std::extent_v<decltype(funcs)>);

    return funcs[choice](arg);
};
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+foo_one(T+arg)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22foo_one%5Cn%22%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+foo_two(T+arg)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22foo_one%5Cn%22%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+foo_choose(int+choice,+T+arg)%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+void+(*funcs%5B%5D)(T)+%3D+%7B+foo_one%3CT%3E,+foo_two%3CT%3E+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++assert(choice+%3E+0+%26%26+choice+%3C+std::extent_v%3Cdecltype(funcs)%3E)%3B%0A%0A++++return+funcs%5Bchoice%5D(arg)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+choice+%3D+1%3B%0A++++float+arg+%3D+1.5%3B%0A++++foo_choose(choice,+arg)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:70.28231797919761,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:29.717682020802382,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

An explanation why your original approach didn't work was already given by other answers here. I don't think I could add to that…

Comment: Would be nice to use `std::function` instead of using function pointers. That would allow to be `foo_one<T>, foo_two<T>` etc. being simply _callable objects_ and such be more generic.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ but it would also incur a potentially significant runtime overhead rather than being a constexpr construct that completely compiles away into nothingness. So unless you really need a heterogeneous map of callables, I would not touch `std::function`. Personally, before touching `std::function`, I'd most likely just go with a switch/if cascade here…or rethink whether it really is necessary to switch between different function implementations based on an integer index to begin with…

Comment: Well, the first thing came to my mind was using a SFINAE oriented solution, rather  than applying  runtime overhead. Not sure that this would have been the right track from the guts. Though I belive the overhead coming with usage of `std::function` would completely come with instantiation of the concrete _callable objects_. If its a simple function pointer, wrapping it won't cost much, or at least being optimized out by the compiler at all. If it's something more complex like a `class` type or _lambda expression_, the performance overhead is lying there.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think the main issue here is that, due to the nature of `std::function`, an implementation necessarily has to rely on type erasure stuff and/or runtime polymorphism, which will give the optimizer a hard time. Also, our function map would have to be, e.g, a dynamically-initialized static local variable. It doesn't seem that any major compiler is able to see through stuff that's using `std::function`, even if we just use it to wrap plain function pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/PMpjGP compare this to https://godbolt.org/z/6zpw-0 …

Comment: Good reasonings regarding optimization, yes.

Comment: Though my gut feeling says there should be a compile time solution for the OP's problem, introducing a variadic parameter pack for the concrete function pointers (callable objects) somehow. Would require more info about the concrete use cases maybe.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ granted, all of that is likely irrelevant if we're talking about classic factory functions that would probably be used to dynamically create objects as the question seems to suggest…

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ well, one could definitely just use a recursive variadic template to generate the necessary cascade of if statements. Above approach will compile down to a simple jump table…

Answer (score 0):

#### Minor point

There is no need to use

```
using foo = foo_one<T>;
```

followed by

```
foo(arg);
```

You might as well use

```
foo_one(arg);
```

#### More important

As you have already noticed, using cascading `if`/`else` statements is a maintenance problem and easily leads to bugs.

It would be better if you could keep a map of functions/functors that can be used to dispatch a call to the appropriate function. However, with function templates, I don't think there is a clear common type one can use to create map of functions/functors.

Let's home somebody else has the right idea to show that it can be done.

Comment: The minor point is fair, however when the number of args is large, along with the number of foos, then a single function declaration of `foo_choose` can be very large.  I'm refactoring, thus I've seen how ugly that approach can get.  @NathanOliver's answer seems to do the job for my needs, but I wonder if there are any weakness you perceive.

Comment: @PrunusPersica, nothing more than what I already mentioned in my answer.